# Redirect Page in PHP with User Input and new Session

Tags: php, validation

I need to get back to my previous page and display the input of user with display error.

What I did was this

```
pageone.php
$_SESSION['serial_validation']='validation';
header("location:javascript://history.go(-1)");


page2.php
if(isset($_SESSION["serial_validation"]))
{
echo $_SESSION["serial_validation"];
}
```

But the redirected page doesnt read the session, any idea on how to prompt this validation ?

Comment: on both page you need to have `session_start();` code on top. Also what you stated in language, you code seems just oposit of that.

Comment: @Anant I already did, this code was a shorten one.

Comment: `page1.php
if(isset($_SESSION["serial_validation"]))
{
echo $_SESSION["serial_validation"];
}

page2.php

$_SESSION['serial_validation']='validation';

if(!empty($_SESSION['serial_validation'])){
 
 header("location:page1.php");
}`

Comment: @Anant What I need is to display back what the user is already inputted then display another Error Validation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

**Data processing page:**

```
<?php
session_start();

$_SESSION['errorMSg'] = 'Your message';
// set the error msg in session

$_SESSION['oldValue'] = 'Old value inputted by user';
// Old value inputted by user

header('location:url.php');
// redirect user to specified location

?>
```

**url.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

// check if error msg exist
if(isset($_SESSION['errorMSg']))
{
    echo $_SESSION['errorMSg'];
    // display error message

    echo '<input type="text" value="'. $_SESSION['oldValue'] .'" />';
    // In the same way you can get all old input value and set them
}

?>
```

Comment: What I need is to display back what the user is already inputted then display another Error Validation, if I use location:url, inputted data of user will be lost.

Comment: this will work, but currently Im using input text with array, inputting around hundreds of serials, do you have any idea where I can just click back and display the error ?

Comment: You can set multiple session or array in a session. Use array keys to identify the sequence to display the error

Comment: I see so that is the only way you think ? if no one gives their answer for about an hour ill upvote your code thank you mayank.